How to catch errors inside request.done() in ajax jquery?
I'm new to jquery.
I have a script to send a request to an API. Basically everything is working fine. Now I'm trying to simulate a network connection error, and show an appropriate error message to the user using an alert. request.fail() gives only error. request.done() however shows:

POST
http://some.api.url
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I have searched quite a lot now, but strangely haven't found any simple implementations to catch errors inside the done() method. Maybe I'm searching the wrong way. I hope I don't have to use regexp for this... Could you please point me to the right direction?

It sounds like you're trying to handle network errors in a jQuery AJAX request and show an alert when there's a failure, but you're only seeing the error within .done(). Normally, error handling should be handled in the .fail() method, which is intended specifically for handling request failures, including network errors.
$.ajax({
    url: "http://apiaddress",
    type: "POST",
    data: { /* your data here */ }
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("Request successful");
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("An error occurred: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
});


It sounds like you are using ChatGPT to answer - that is banned here

Agreed with @mplungjan : https://prnt.sc/QPzxwC0ZiPZ0
